# ImportError: No module named django_extensions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-extensions

I am completely new to python as well as to Django. I got a sample Django Rest project. When I run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named django_extensions
```

How can I solve this?

I am running it in a virtualenv

Comment: are you running your project by `/path/to/your/virtual-environment/bin/python manage.py makemigrations`  or just `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: agree with @hari , check if your virtual env is activated or not , because if django is installed then this error should not occured .

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It looks as if your sample project relies on [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can install it by activating your virtualenv, then running:

```
pip install django-extensions
```

Once you have installed django-extensions, you may get a different import error if there are other packages missing from your virtualenv. Hopefully, your sample project will have a `requirements.txt` file which lists the requirements. If so, you can install the required packages with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: and when i install djangorestframework_swagger, it shows an error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangorestframework_swagger (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for djangorestframework_swagger
". can u help me on this?

Comment: If the requirements file for the sample project contains `djangorestframework_swagger`, and it won't install, then you might want to open a bug report. If you search `djangorestframework_swagger` the closest match appears to be `django-rest-swagger`, so you could try `pip install django-rest-swagger`.

Comment: thanks again. But still i got some issues on this project. Can u plz help on this?  When i run makemigrations, error is "No module named models" on line "from gcm.models import get_device_model"

Comment: No, I can't help with that, because it sounds like a different problem to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package using below command:

```
pip install django-extensions
```

after installing it in your django project, you have load this extension by inserting it in INSTALLED_APPS defined settings.py file of your project like the following way

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_extensions'
]

Just append 'django_extensions' element in list of INSTALLED_APPS

Thanks :)